# PyCharm virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-venv

I try to create an empty venv in pycharm 2022.1.3 but it creates venv with all libraries from base interpreter (python3.10.12) even when "inherit global-site packages" is off.

I created an empty venv using python3.10-venv via the terminal, then checked that this venv is really empty with pip list. but when i try this venv in pycharm, it displays all the libraries from the base interpreter. and when i activate this venv in pycharm terminal and run pip list, it also shows all libraries, i don't know where is the error. tried to solve this with pyenv but with this i cant install any library in pycharm...
I'm using linux mint 20.1.
Please don't throw rocks at me, this is my first question here)